# zfs users recognize the output of "zfs list -r" for me one pool is very different

Tags: zfs

any zfs user is familiar with the output of "zfs list -r"

On one pool  "zfs list -r  poolX"
It lists all the the snapshots in every zfs filesystem on that pool, and nothing else.

I have not found any different settings compared to other pools.  But there must be something I inadvertently set/unset.

Can anyone offer some ideas to track this down?

Answer (score 0):

A dataset could be from different types: `filesystem`, `volume` or `snapshot`, etc.

`-r` is *recursive* listing. If you just see snapshots, it's because the only datasets present are `snapshot`

Use `-t` to limit the list on dataset type as mentioned in [documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man8/zfs.8.html)